# XSS Torture Test - does it exist?

Tags: testing, xss, user-input

I'm looking to write a html sanitiser, and obviously to test/prove that it works properly, I need a set of XSS examples to pitch against it to see how it performs. Here's a [nice example from Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001167.html)

```
<img src=""http://www.a.com/a.jpg<script type=text/javascript 
src="http://1.2.3.4:81/xss.js">" /><<img 
src=""http://www.a.com/a.jpg</script>"
```

I know there's a [Mime Torture Test](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=32721&package_id=98949) which comprises of several nested emails with attachments that's used to test Mime decoders (if they can decode it properly, then they've been proven to work). I'm basically looking for an equivilent for XSS, i.e. a list of examples of dodgy html that I can throw at my sanitiser just to make sure it works OK.

If anyone also has any good resources on how to write the sanitiser (i.e. what common exploits people try to use, etc) they'd be gratefully received too.

Thanks in advance :-)

Edit: Sorry if this wasn't clear before, but I was after a set of torture tests so I can write unit tests for the sanitiser, not test it in the browser, etc. The source data in theory may have come from anywhere - not just a browser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at this XSS Cheat List : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Specifically the "XML format of the XSS Cheat Sheet", which I missed the first time I saw that page..

Answer (score 7):

[XSS Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7598) is a great Firefox plugin you can run against your sanitizer.

Comment: The link to "XSS Me" is formatted wrong... The correct URL is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7598

Comment: It is outdated, does not work with the latest version of FireFox

Answer (score 2):

Check out [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page). They have good guidance on how XSS works, what to look for, and even the [WebGoat](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project) project, where you can try your hand on a vulnerable site.

Answer (score 2):

You might try Jesse Ruderman's jsfunfuzz (http://www.squarefree.com/2007/08/02/introducing-jsfunfuzz/) that throws random data at your Javascript trying to break it. It seems the Firefox team has used this with great success.